# Multi Language website with subfolders, what to do with root domain?

Tags: seo, magento, multilingual

I am setting a Magento multilanguage website with subfolder as suggested by many SEO and Google guideline.

For example:

```
example.com/it (Italian default)
example.com/en (English)
example.com/fr (French)
example.com/de (German)
example.com     (what to do with this?)
```

Magento makes it easy using "Add Store Code to URLs" showing correct language for each subfolder.

I read many threads about language subfolders but none of them is suggesting what to to with the root domain `example.com`.

My default language is `/it`, I may be wrong but it seems that Magento keeps default language content both on `example.com` and `example.com/it`.

So what is best practice for when a user get to `example.com`?

Comment: Is `example.com` exactly the same as `example.com/it`? And do links from `example.com` point to `example.com/it`and its sub folders?

Comment: Yes this is the standard way Magento handle subfolders when configuring with the setting "Add store code to urls". Example.com has exactly the same as example.com/it  and links from example.com point to example.com/it and its sub folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several possibilities:

#### Choose one language

Choose one language and redirect.   If you have a "main" language then this might be the best option.

#### Automatically detect the language

Use the Accept-Language header that the browser sends and automatically redirect appropriately.   Google does this for international visitors.

Using *.htaccess* and mod_rewrite you could use code like this to make it happen:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (de) [NC]
RewriteRule index.html http://example.com/de/ [R,L]
```

#### Offer users a choice

Ikea uses this solution:  [image]

So does Wikipedia.

Comment: Well I like the option: "Use the Accept-Language header that the browser sends and automatically redirect appropriately. Google does this for international visitors". Do you also have any tip how to set this option with htaccess?

Comment: I've added .htaccess code for that case

Answer (score 0):

If your default language is /it, then make example.com/it as your default home page with italic content. Show appropriate version of content for your users. Regrading example.com English content will be best practice for users